# Android Debugging wont work XSLT error

Tags: android, debugging, xslt, java

I ran my program just fine a few minutes ago, and when I added more functionality now it is telling me "The JRE Instance Default XSLT processor does not support debugging_ Would you like to debug using the default Xalan 2.7.1 processor instead?"

I did restart Eclipse maybe that has something to do with it? :/

It's my first times writing an app so if I have to set something in eclipse each time maybe that's why? and what is it if that is the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You were in an XML file when you hit debug, I would bet. Happens to me all the time. For some annoying reason it does something entirely different that I don't understand when you do that. Delete the .out.xml that should probably have been created, open a .java file, and try to debug again. Another way is to just right-click your project and do Run As > Android Application.